# Can I turn my existing Ubuntu installation to Ubuntu Core (ARM)

Tags: ubuntu, arm, armbian

I'm using an Orange Pi Zero ARM board that uses the Allwinner  H2+ SoC. I tried installing Alpine Linux because a want a really lightweight distro for my project. Sadly it didn't work. Hence, I had to download and use Armbian (https://armbian.com/orange-pi-zero/), based on Ubuntu Focal Fossa. It is indeed lightweight but I need something even lighter. Hence, is there any way to convert my existing system to Ubuntu Core? Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Try a web search with keywords `alpine linux arm` - it looks promising.